# Rails - Error pushing to Heroku - not seeing Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've been receiving this error for most of the day now, and my brain is too fried to keep trying to determine what the issue is:

[image: Heroku Push Error]

It appears to be saying that I don't have a Gemfile.lock in version control, however, here is the Gemfile.lock that I currently have - as seen from github:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.2)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.2)
    activeadmin (0.3.2)
      devise (>= 1.1.2)
      fastercsv
      formtastic (< 2.0.0)
      inherited_resources (< 1.3.0)
      kaminari (>= 0.12.4)
      meta_search (>= 0.9.2)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.0)
    activemodel (3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
    activesupport (3.1.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.6)
    ansi (1.3.0)
    arel (2.2.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1-x86-mingw32)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
    devise (1.4.9)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      warden (~> 1.0.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.2.9)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    fastercsv (1.5.4)
    formtastic (1.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 2.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.7)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    has_scope (0.5.1)
    heroku (2.11.0)
      launchy (>= 0.3.2)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      rubyzip
      term-ansicolor (~> 1.0.5)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    inherited_resources (1.2.2)
      has_scope (~> 0.5.0)
      responders (~> 0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.16)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.1)
    kaminari (0.12.4)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    launchy (2.0.5)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    mail (2.3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    meta_search (1.1.1)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.1.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.1.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    multi_json (1.0.3)
    orm_adapter (0.0.5)
    pg (0.11.0-x86-mingw32)
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.2)
    rack (1.3.5)
    rack-cache (1.1)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activerecord (= 3.1.1)
      activeresource (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.1)
    railties (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.11)
      json (~> 1.4)
    responders (0.6.4)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rubyzip (0.9.4)
    sass (3.1.10)
    sass-rails (3.1.4)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.4)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.0)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    sprockets (2.0.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.4-x86-mingw32)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turn (0.8.3)
      ansi
    tzinfo (0.3.30)
    uglifier (1.0.4)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.0.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.1)
  devise (~> 1.4.7)
  heroku
  jquery-rails
  pg
  rails (= 3.1.1)
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.4)
  sqlite3
  turn
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Steps I've tried:

- Deleted Gemfile.lock and ran bundle update to generate new one
- Specifically stated "git add Gemfile.lock" before pushing to
  github
- I pulled the sass-rails gem out of assets in case it was needed in
  production
- Deleted the contents of .gitignore to make sure there    wasn't any
  dependency being ignored

If it helps, this is a Rails 3.1.1 app and I'm also using ActiveAdmin.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of all occurrences of `-x86-mingw32` in the gem specs as well as lines

```
PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32
```

as Alex mentioned.

I understand why Heroku now requires Gemfile.lock, but overall I disagree with the practice.

Comment: Hi wizard, do you know if this is this a recent change?  I have a few apps running on Heroku already that are using 3.0.10 and they all have references to x86-mingw32.

Comment: Heroku had announce their intentions to do this quite some time ago.  I still get warnings from my apps on Bamboo-1.8.7, but I got the same error as you when trying to deploy to Cedar stack.  Making the changes I suggested fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'm having some other issues but this got me past the Bundler problem.  The answers were both similar but I'm upvoting both and marking this one as the answer because of the extra communication.  Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 3):

Heroku won't let you use a Gemfile.lock generated on Windows. Your best bet is to create your .lock file on a *nix system. Use a Mac, Linux running on [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) etc.

Alternatively, you can try deleting the lines

```
PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32
```

although this may cause problems.

Comment: Hmmm... that's weird.  I currently have several apps that are running on Heroku and they were all made in Windows and they all have a Gemfile.lock with various occurrences of x86-mingw32.  I haven't had any issues at all with those.  The only difference is that this one is running Rails 3.1.1 and the others are using Rails 3.0.10.  Is this only an issue with the newer releases?